# Face setting doesn't work for client sessions

Tags: init-file, emacsclient, faces, server

I wanted to change the colours of Anzu's counter, taking the foreground from the Isearch match background and the background from the fringes, like this

[image]

So I evaluated

```
(face-spec-set 'anzu-mode-line `((t :foreground ,(face-attribute 'isearch :background)
                                    :background ,(face-attribute 'fringe :background)))
               'face-defface-spec)
```

and it worked. I added it to my `init.el`, restarted the emacs server... and then it looked like this:

[image]

How do I fix that?

---

PS If I launch Emacs from the command line instead of opening a client frame, then the faces get the right colours. It also works if I put strings in place of the `face-attribute` forms:

```
(face-spec-set 'anzu-mode-line '((t :foreground "magenta3"
                                    :background "grey95"))
               'face-defface-spec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Emacs 27 provides `server-after-make-frame-hook`, which makes it easier to copy face properties for client sessions.

```
(defun my-anzu-faces ()
  (face-spec-set 'anzu-mode-line `((t
                                    :foreground ,(face-attribute 'isearch :background)
                                    :background ,(face-attribute 'mode-line-inactive :background)))
                 'face-defface-spec))
(if (daemonp)
    (add-hook 'server-after-make-frame-hook #'my-anzu-faces)
  (my-anzu-faces))
```

This works for client sessions as well as stand-alone ones.

---

Well, it seemed that the problem was that the face properties which I wanted `anzu-mode-line` to take were still unspecified at the time of setting it, so I kept on messing around with hooks and `with-eval-after-load` until I came up with this

```
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
          (lambda (frame)
            (with-selected-frame frame
              (face-spec-set 'anzu-mode-line `((t
                                                :foreground ,(face-attribute 'isearch :background)
                                                :background ,(face-attribute 'fringe :background)))
                             'face-defface-spec))))
```

As you can probably guess, I'm not sure it is the optimal solution, but it is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `custom-set-faces` instead (not tested).

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
  '(anzu-mode-line ((t (:foreground ,(face-attribute 'isearch :background)
                        :background ,(face-attribute 'fringe :background))))))
```

Comment: Niet, it looks the same as in the second picture in the question. I've noticed that the customize menu reports `((t (:background "gray" :foreground unspecified)))` as the value of the face and I have no idea why.

Comment: Maybe because isearch and fringe need to be set first?

Comment: I thought that too, so I tried with `with-eval-after-load 'isearch` and the `after-make-frame-functions` hook but it didn't change anything.